# Linux Lubuntu wrong keys displayed

Tags: linux, keyboard, lubuntu

So my problem that when I change my language from American to Lithuanian all  specials symbols like (ą,ž) are displayed incorect for example then I press Q it displays ą then I press f it displays š it should be that when I change language  all special symbols are displayed instead of 1234567890-= I`m using laptop, I tried to change keyboard models, but it did not change anything I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the system tray, click "Add/Remove Panel Items", click on panel applets, click on add, select "Keyboard Layout Handler." Add that and close all those windows.

In the lower right, you'll now have a Keyboard Layout Handler icon. Right click on that, untick the bit about keeping system layouts, and then add/change/remove keyboard layouts as you wish.

The solution is a bit of an ordeal until you're used to it.