# How can I use quotes and cedilla without having to press the right alt key in the international American keyboard layout?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using Gentoo and dwm. My keyboard is configured with the command

```
setxkbmap us -variant alt-intl
```

but whenever I need to use double or single quotes or cedilla, I need to press the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.
How can I configure my keyboard so I don't have to press <kbd>alt</kbd>, just the quote key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Check if the dead_acute is set:

  `xmodmap -pke | grep dead_acute`
- Else, get the keycode: `xev`
- And set the flag with:

  `xmodmap -e "keycode 48 = dead_acute dead_diaeresis dead_acute dead_diaeresis apostrophe quotedbl apostrophe"`
- Put this in your `~/.XCompose`:

```
include "%L"

#  Overriding C with acute:
<dead_acute> <C>            : "Ç" Ccedilla  # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<dead_acute> <c>            : "ç" ccedilla  # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

- And this in your `~/.xinitrc`:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim         # Make compose key work
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim
```

Answer (score 3):

You're better off with the `English (intl, with AltGr dead keys)` layout. How you install/select it will vary with your distro and desktop environment. For example, I explained how to do so with Lubuntu with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577903/linux-lubuntu-wrong-keys-displayed/590178#590178).

Using this layout means you don't have to press the quote button twice, but you still have access to the characters you're (probably) looking for.

In this case, the 'AltGr' means your right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Pressing and holding the right Alt key outputs this:

> äåéëþúíóö (small example)

There's also the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key modifier.Pressing both the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys together outputs this:

> ÄÅÉËÞÜÚÍÓÖ (small example)

And, more importantly, just pressing the <kbd>'</kbd> once will output the `'` as the expected behavior. This English keyboard layout is suitable for *most* characters that one will need in day-to-day operations.

Because it will depend on your desktop environment and distro, I can only show you how it looks on my system. This is where I went to configure this:

[image: Keyboard Layout Handler]

Comment: This works in parts. Before I didn't need to press alt to put the tilde now I need it and I still need to hold the alt to put the cedilla.

Comment: I tried these: intl, alt-intl, altgr-intl.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use both the alt key and (sometimes) the shift key. Unless you choose a specific language (other than English) these two things are your only real options - that I'm aware of.

Comment: I set the locale to pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8. Now I can use the ç ã without pressing alt, but the quotation marks cannot.

Comment: If your local keyboard settings don't meet your needs, you pretty much *have* to use the alt key. You can re-map keys, if you want. If you do, then you'll want to start with a keyboard layout that most closely matches your needs and go from there. [Follow this link](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor) to learn more. However, I'd recommend acclimating to using the alt key. In time, you'll get used to it and it becomes second nature. Personally, I've used it for decades. It's just ingrained at this point.

Comment: eventually i need to program on windows and mac, and this key exchange always confuses me. But thank you very much, I'll see if I can remap the keys.